# How can I prevent gcc for arm in Platformio optimizing away a function that is not used

Tags: c, gcc, arm, stm32, platformio

I have got NUCLEO-F411RE and I am having some issues when developing in VSCode with Platformio. There seems to be some optimization that I can not switch off.

I have this code:

```
#pragma GCC optimize("O0")

#include "stm32f411xe.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define GPIOAEN     (1U<<0)
#define GPIOCEN     (1U<<2)
#define PIN5        (1U<<5)
#define PIN13       (1U<<13)
#define LED_PIN     PIN5
#define BTN_PIN     PIN13
#define UART2EN     (1U<<17)
void uart_2_init(void);
void uart2_write(int ch);
void ms_delay(int ms)
{
   while (ms-- > 0) {
      volatile int x=500;
      while (x-- > 0)
         __asm("nop");
   }
}
int __io_putchar(int ch){
    uart2_write(ch);
    return ch;
}

int main(){
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= (GPIOAEN | GPIOCEN);

    GPIOA->MODER |= (1U<<10);
    GPIOA->MODER &=~(1U<<11);

    GPIOC->MODER &=~(1U<<26);
    GPIOC->MODER &=~(1U<<27);
    uart_2_init();
    while (1)
    {
        ms_delay(200);
        printf("hello again from stm32\n\r");

    }

}
void uart_2_init(void){
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= GPIOAEN;
    RCC->APB1ENR  |= UART2EN;

    //PA2 and PA3 alternate
    GPIOA->MODER &=~(1U<<4);
    GPIOA->MODER |= (1U<<5);
    //Alternate function selection
    GPIOA->AFR[0] |= (1U<<8);
    GPIOA->AFR[0] |= (1U<<9);
    GPIOA->AFR[0] |= (1U<<10);
    GPIOA->AFR[0] &=~(1U<<11);
    // USART2 settings
    USART2->BRR = 0x0683;
    USART2->CR1 = 0x0008;
    USART2->CR2 = 0x0000;
    USART2->CR3 = 0x0000;
    USART2->CR1 |=0x2000;
}

void uart2_write(int ch){
    while (!(USART2->SR & 0x0080)){}
    USART2->DR = (ch & 0xFF);

}
```

When I compile and upload it from STMCubeIDE it works, but from VSCode and Platformio it does compile but it does not do anything. So it seems that it is being optimized away as it is not used.
This is what is in platformio.ini

```
[env:nucleo_f411re]
platform = ststm32
board = nucleo_f411re
framework = cmsis
build_flags =
  -Wall
  -O0
  -v
build_type = debug
```

I have also tried declaring function as volatile.

```
volatile int __io_putchar(int ch){
    uart2_write(ch);
    return ch;
}
```

Comment: Try: `int __attribute__((used)) __io_putchar(int ch)`

Comment: `used` is _exactly_ for your desired use case. So, I'm surprised it's not working. It's a `gcc` thing [AFAIK] so does your compiler support it? What about `Platformio`? You could try to make the compiler think it is used by doing in `main` (e.g.) `if (__ioputchar != NULL) uart_2_init();` The `if` clause should always be true.

Comment: Have you checked the assembly, that it is actually optimized out? It could not work for many other reasons.

Comment: If it is unused, why does the program need it? Where is the reference hidden, in some standard library? And why doesn't Platformio have this reference? Does it use other standard libraries? Please [edit] your question and add your research results.

Comment: https://www.openstm32.org/forumthread1346#threadId7500 lead to answer. I needed file called syscalls.c in same directory with main.c. STMCubeIDE generates it but Platformio in VSCode does not. Thanks Support Ukraine.